# What is the best way to connect a WebCam in graphedit?

Tags: directx, directshow, windows-api-code-pack, graphedit

When I Connect them in this manner it open the camera but with black no Images or video display:

[image: Integrated Webcam => MJPEG Decompressor => Color Space Converter => Video Renderer]

How can I connect the WebCam successfully?

Comment: Yes I mean it..

Comment: OK I added the tag then.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403000/868014 "Smart Tee" part

Comment: It is an integrated camera. It could output a format which is not the one you are expecting. If it is the case you may need to use MediaFoundation instead of DirectShow and edit the data to be in RGB format before you render it. I had the same problem with an old integrated webcam which is outputting YUY2.

Comment: See to capture from webcam: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640023/project-and-build-structure-for-microsoft-directshow-based-virtual-webcam-applic